# How go get both both key and value from firebase database on kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm  new to android development and im having a bit of problem with firebase database. I'm creating a app somewhat similar to e-commerce application.

```
category1
    child1
         name: nameOfChild1
         value: value
    child2
         name: nameOfChild2
         value: value
    child3
```

This is how my database is structured. im using

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("requiredCategory")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (productSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val product = productSnapshot.getValue(Product::class.java)
                        productlist.add(product!!)
                    }
                    productrecyclerview.adapter = productAdapter(productlist)
                }
            }
```

And `Product` class is

```
data class Product(
    var id: String? = null,
    var price: String? = null,
)
```

Instead i would like to change my structure to

```
category1
    child1
      nameOfNested1: value
      nameOfNested2: value
    child2
      nameOfNested1: value
      nameOfNested2: value
    child3
      nameOfNested1: Value
      nameOfNested2: value

category2
    child1
    child2
    child3
```

I want to retrive both the `key: nameOfNested` and `value:value` .How do i go on and change the code get both the id and value?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to get the key of each product, you can do so with:

```
for (productSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
    val key = productSnapshot.key // 
    val product = productSnapshot.getValue(Product::class.java)
    ...
```

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. each of the `child` is currently stored with `name : productname` and `price: productprice`. What this code currently does is it looks for the key and retrives the vlaue. instead when the `child` is referenced, i want it to retrive all the `keys` along with their `values`  so that i can create a structure that looks like this `productname: productprice`

Comment: The new line of code that I incuded in my answer (`val key = productSnapshot.key`) shows how to get the key of each child node. Did you try it? What did it do? Was there an error message?

Comment: It was giving the key of first member `child1` and was erroring out. I found that the issue was with using `.getvalue()` and using a class. The solution would have worked if i was the old database structure. I got it fixed. thank you for your reply

Comment: I have no idea wht that means, but good to hear you got it working @George. Do you think you can write up the solution as an answer, so that future visitors may benefit from it?

Comment: I hope the answer below clarifies everything. i'm the worst when it comes to explaining things

Comment: In your answer get get the key of the snapshot with `student.name = studentSnapshot.key.toString()`, which is exactly the same as what I pointed out in my answer (except that the `toString()` is not needed as `key` is a `String` already). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer with what i got working and also be a bit more specific about what i was trying to accomplish

First of all, let me start with what i was doing. i had a Firebase Realtime Database that looked like this
`(Only an example for demonstration purpose)`

```
Students
   Riya
     name: Riya 
     class: 10
   Benson
     name: Benson
     class: 9
   Merlin
     name: Merlin
     class: 7
```

I Made a student class that looks like this

```
data class Student(
    var name: String? = null,
    var class: String? = null,
)
```

I found a snippet online that would retrieve data from db that is given below

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (studentSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val student = studentSnapshot.getValue(Student::class.java)
                       studentlist.add(student!!)
                    }
                    myrecyclerview.adapter = thisAdapter(studentlist)
                }
            }
```

It gave a Array that look something like this

```
[Student(name=Riya, class=10), Student(name=Benson, class=9), Student(name=Merlin, class=7)]
```

As you can see, the structure that i was using was inefficient and i want to change it. Also, instead of a single `Students` refence  i wanted to add child which holds the students based on the class they are in. Also i wanted to add `age` property to each student as well. So i came up with a structure that looks like this

```
Students
   Class7
      Joe: 12
      Mary: 11
      Ann: 12
   Class8
      Michael: 12
      Lucy: 12
   Class9
      Ricko: 15
      Anna: 14

Staff
    class7
      Janet:25
      Bob: 34
```

What i was having issue with getting Both the Key and value at the same time. what at the time i was using was

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Students")
            .child(requiredClass)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (studentSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                     val student = studentSnapshot.getValue(Student::class.java)
                            studentlist.add(student!!)
                        }
```

It was not working with what i had.. It was looking for ids `name` and `age`. (i renamed the `class` to `age` in the `Student` class)

I got it working by doing something like this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Students")
            .child(requiredClass)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (studentSnapshot in snapshot.children) {

                            val student = Student()
                            student.name = studentSnapshot.key.toString()
                            student.age = studentSnapshot.value.toString()
                            studentlist.add(student!!)
                        }
```

This works fine and returns a array that i wanted.

I know most of that explanation was unnecessary. i wanted to clarify what my situation was. Also my solution might be the worst. If anyone have a better solution, i'm all ears...